# What am I doing wrong when trying to handle my own exception in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a very simple exception in my Spring Boot application:

```
package tech.dashman.server.controllers.support;

public class BadRequestException extends Exception {
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to turn it into a `BAD_REQUEST` in my `ControllerAdvice` that looks like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    // Other handlers that just work

    @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleValidationError(BadRequestException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

When I start the application, it crashes with this message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity tech.dashman.server.controllers.support.RestExceptionHandler.handleValidationError(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at tech.dashman.server.DashmanServerApplication.main(DashmanServerApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity tech.dashman.server.controllers.support.RestExceptionHandler.handleValidationError(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException]: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity tech.dashman.server.controllers.support.RestExceptionHandler.handleValidationError(org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), public final org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException(java.lang.Exception,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)}
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.addExceptionMapping(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.<init>(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:76) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:269) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:245) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:450) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:826) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa3dc8d5.CGLIB$handlerExceptionResolver$31(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa3dc8d5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1ee68c67.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa3dc8d5.handlerExceptionResolver(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

which I'm having trouble understanding. What's going on? What's the correct way of doing this?

The other handlers look like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException manve, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = getErrorDetail(manve);
        errorDetail.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        errorDetail.setTitle(ErrorDetail.VALIDATION_FAILED);
        errorDetail.setDetail("Input validation failed");
        errorDetail.addFieldErrors(manve.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetail, null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleNotFoundException(MethodArgumentNotValidException manve, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = getErrorDetail(manve);
        errorDetail.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        errorDetail.setTitle("Not Found");
        errorDetail.setDetail("Resource not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetail, null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    private ErrorDetail getErrorDetail(MethodArgumentNotValidException manve) {
        ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail();
        errorDetail.setTimeStamp(new Date().getTime());
        errorDetail.setDeveloperMessage(manve.getClass().getName());
        return errorDetail;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleValidationError(BadRequestException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the "other handlers that just work" (specifically, their signatures). It looks like you have method overloads that Spring is having difficulty resolving.

Comment: @chrylis: done, I updated the question.

Comment: The NotFound handler looks wrong... I'm not even sure if that's working. Removing it allows the app to start. Haven't tested it yet.

Comment: It really doesn't look like the `BRE` handler is involved. The message indicates that it's your `MANVE` handler it doesn't like.

Comment: Please, search your project for **handlerExceptionResolver** keyword and provide places where it is met (configuration? bean's ids?)

Comment: It seems like it actually works after removing the NotFound handler.

Comment: The NotFound handler has a method parameter of type `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. IIRC method argument type takes precedence over annotation parameter. Therefore you effectively have two handlers for `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, therefore "ambiguous"

Comment: @chrylis: if you want to add your comments as a question, I'll polish them with what I did and accept it.